# How to identify a pop-up and kill it

Tags: suspend, notification

I see a boring popup that states

> Computer will suspend very soon because of inactivity

When I log back in to my desktop after it went to sleep. I would like to try to write some program that make this popup automatically disappear as soon as I log in, but I don't know how to identify this small window. I tried to diff the outputs of `sudo ps ax` with & without the pop-up displayed but this shows no difference.

I've already read [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1232454).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that `sudo su wininfo` gives me the info I need.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me to find another tool: xwininfo. I used wmctrl -i -c to close the popup